# Find attribute relates to subscriber on Subscriber Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, subscriber-key

I have been trying to find a way to get the attribute in each custom data extension that relates to subscriber on Subscriber Key.

[image]

I was trying to use SOAP API according to the code below. But, I did not see any attribute in each custom data extension that relates to subscriber on Subscriber Key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionTemplate</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Description</Properties>
            <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
            <Properties>IsTestable</Properties>
            <Properties>SendableCustomObjectField</Properties>
            <Properties>SendableSubscriberField</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodLength</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure</Properties>
            <Properties>RowBasedRetention</Properties>
            <Properties>ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport</Properties>
            <Properties>DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod</Properties>
            <Properties>RetainUntil</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: its the <Properties>SendableCustomObjectField</Properties>

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that in your SOAP call, you are calling to the `DataExtensionTempalte` object and should instead be targeting the `DataExtension` object. I am assuming this based on it sounds like you want each individual Data Extension and not an overall Data Extension Template that is used to help create boilerplates for new DEs.

Then inside the `DataExtension` Object, you would target `SendableDataExtensionField.Name` and the `SendableSubscriberField.Name`.  This will get you the fields you are looking for.

Something like this will get you where you need to be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Description</Properties>
            <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
            <Properties>IsTestable</Properties>
            <Properties>SendableDataExtensionField.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>SendableSubscriberField.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodLength</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure</Properties>
            <Properties>RowBasedRetention</Properties>
            <Properties>ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport</Properties>
            <Properties>DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod</Properties>
            <Properties>RetainUntil</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

That being said, the call you showed in your sample will work for grabbing it from the 'data extension templates' you have in your account and you would utilize the `SendableCustomObjectField` to get the field that is default set in each template. From there you could then run a call against the DataExtension object looking at Template.CustomerKey to filter your return to see each DE that uses that relationship;